# How to replicate this graph like this (single linkage)?

Tags: r, dendrogram

```
library(stats)
d <- matrix(0,5,5)


d[lower.tri(d)] <- c(9,3,6,11,7,5,10,9,2,8)
d <- d+t(d)
d <- as.dist(d)
hc.s <- hclust(d, "single")

plot(hc.s,hang=-1)
```

[image]

This graph is okay, but the axis is ugly. In my textbook, the figure is as below: How to make my graph in the same way as the textbook?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to change exactly? Try to be more specific / less subjective than one is ugly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own axes

```
par( mar=c(5,5,8,16) )
plot( hc.s,hang=-1, axes=F, labels=F )
axis( 1, 1:length(hc.s$order), labels=hc.s$order, col=NA, pos=0.2 )
axis( 2, 0:max(hc.s$height), las=1 )
points( 1:5, rep(0,5), pch=19 )
```

[image: dendrogram plot]

Comment: This is really nice! Do you know how to mark 1,,3,5,2,4 as solid circles?

Comment: @Mariana See edits. A bit hacky, but works.

Comment: After the first two lines, it says "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large".

Comment: @Mariana Outputs can be different depending on operating system and displays. You can play around with the values in the first line. Try e.g. c(5,5,8,12). These numbers set the margins for bottom, left, top and right in this order.

Comment: Now after these codes, the y-axis name is Height. How to change it to Distance? Also, the name of x-axis of current figure is hclust(*, "single"). How to change the name of x-axis to Objects?

Comment: @Mariana Just add `sub="", xlab="Objects", ylab="Distance"` to `plot` as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

try using `factoextra`

```r
library(factoextra)
fviz_dend(hc.s)
```

[image]